# How I can move the legend outside the chart?

Tags: primefaces

I have a chart that should go filling up as I select an item from a table to compare the level of sales per customer is selected. That works correctly but the legend is shown above the graph information.
How I can move the legend outside the chart?

Comment: see pic here: http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=210gkmc&s=8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces: Charts and Legend position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309948/primefaces-charts-and-legend-position)